# Result of LexBFS on an outer-planar graph

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, planar-graphs

Suppose we have an outer-planar graph $G$. Is the following expression true? If yes, please prove it. If no, please give a counterexample.

After running LexBFS on $G$, we will have a vertex order $v_1,...,v_n$ so that $\forall i: indeg(v_i)\leq2$.

Comment: This sounds like a problem you've been given. Where did this problem come from? Do you have any work done towards answering it?

Comment: @Mike Pierce, it was a question is my home-works. I proved it by contradiction, but my proof is lengthy. I will add my proof as soon as possible.